# convert string to byte[]

Tags: c#

How do you convert string to byte[] in C#?

Comment: Keep in mind that the array of bytes you get is entirely dependent upon the string encoding which is being used -- the textual representation of a string is lost if you do not how how it is encoded.

Answer (score 6):

Note that .NET strings are encoded as *Unicode* (UTF-16):

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("a string");
```

Answer (score 6):

using `byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);`

Comment: Yep but I've actually never came close to using any UTF16 specific characters to date and UTF8.GetBytes always did the job (especially when performance is critical)

Comment: I know but I was assuming that the OP wanted the actual bytes that the string contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
var input     = "myValue";
var byteInput = input.ToCharArray ().Select ( character => ( byte ) character ).ToArray ();

Assert.AreEqual ( input, new string ( byteInput.Select ( character => ( char ) character ).ToArray () ) );
```

And add the encoding before or after if encoding is something you want to do.